# Magic story revolving around boy who is "twice of royal blood"

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this children's or teenager fantasy book in the 2000's. It was in Dutch but it may have been translated to Dutch. I know it was in some fantastic setting involving two important countries; there was a central character who was related to both royal houses which was very important (possibly a prophecy around it). The phrase "twice of royal blood" comes to mind.

There was also a magical doomsday weapon that the villain used to freeze places over, but it could also be used for good as by the end it was making a desert fertile.

Comment: Do you remember what the Dutch phrase was that was used for "twice of royal blood"? Google Translate is suggesting to me "tweemaal koninklijk bloed", but I know it's not always right.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Sorry for late response. It sounds right, "koningsbloed" is also used instead of "koninklijk bloed".